# How can I enable monitor mode/install custom driver in my Rooted Huawei Phone?

Tags: kernel, wifi, termux-linux

I have recently Installed **TWRP** and Rooted using **Magisk** my Huawei Mate 10 Lite (**RNE-L21**). And I was able to install Airmon via Termux but soon realized the Intetnal Wifi card doesn't support mon mode. But I have an external wifi card Its the **TP-Link TL-WN722N**. It requires a custom made driver to be installed.

Now is it possible to use Wifi Card with the phone. If necessary I can Modify the kernel of the phone. But I prefer not to because it's difficult to even find huawei kernal let alone modify config.

**What I've tried and expect:**
I have tried enabling monitor mode with internal wifi card but it simply doesn't work as expected. I ordered a Micro Usb OTG and I will try just plugging in the Tp link card but I think I will just get a flashing that card is connected but wont be detected by termux.